# This is not what I thought it was vs This is not what I expected

Tags: conjunctions, imaginary-situations

Suppose that person A closes their eyes. Next, person B gives something to touch. After that, person A must guess what the object is is after touching it. After person A opens their eyes, A says

> "This is not what I thought it was".

I have seen some YouTube videos where this is a correct response. I have a question:

> Why can't we say "*this is not what I expected*" in this situation ? **Further, when can we use, "this is not what I expected" ?**

Comment: When A opens his/her eyes, they now know what the object is, so they would say "This is not what I _thought it was_" or "what I expected."

Comment: Except the tense, we can use the both ?

Comment: No, because as KB said, "they **now know** what the object is. In the past they didn't know, but now - in the present - they do know.

Comment: "This is not what I was expecting," might be more idiomatic, but, yes you can use either verb.

Answer (score 2):

A person's beliefs can change over time.

Assume that you touch a metal coin with your fingers. You are unable to see the coin with your eyes. You might believe that the coin was manufactured from copper.

In the future, you will open your eyes. You will se that the coin is silver. The coin is not copper. The coin does not look orange or brown.

You might say any of the following:

> - "This is not what I thought it was."
> - "This is not what I expected."
> - "This is not what I was expecting."

All three sentences are correct English.

For any **x**, Bob thinks that **x** is red If and only if Bob expects that **x** is red.

Answer (score 0):

When we open a box, then the box might contain some cute toy. We can say the following:

> That is not what I expected. Here, I see a cute toy. I predicted that I would see some food.

Here 'That is not what I expected' **can be interpreted** as the following : This expression indicates how smart I am. Even though I predicted all possible cases coming from the situation, but I missed some case. So the word 'this' in the sentence indicates 'the situation that a cute toy appreared'.

And the word 'that' in the sentence 'That is not what I thought it was' indicates 'the cute toy'.